# CAS services management 4.2 integrating with CAS server (Ldap)

Tags: spring, tomcat, ldap, cas

Used source: [CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Service-Management.html)

I have installed CAS server, configured LDAP and now trying to install **CAS services management** using [cas-services-management-overlay](https://github.com/apereo/cas-services-management-overlay)

I built war file and droped it in Tomcat webapp directory. It started but then I passed login and password it falls into loop.

1. Chrome tells me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
2. This project is under JasperReports Server I mean at first I
   installed JasperServer then add CAS and CAS services to its tomcat`s folder.

**cas-management.log** tells me

```
2016-06-15 10:27:13,515 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - Secret key for encryption is not defined. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the encryption key
2016-06-15 10:27:13,528 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - Generated encryption key 8zQMOHkoeVI45PWAAvBf9ldOG2RdxuZLs5Ucuq-3XDc of size 256. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings.
2016-06-15 10:27:13,528 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - Secret key for signing is not defined. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the signing key
2016-06-15 10:27:13,528 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - Generated signing key ZCrkMuytHNKt3peysMTjLYyzFCZusCfL459cpcunZ7w-3ogVaJ0BciIGeSjDO1b_QqjswJAPjijivF0WcR_vhg of size 512. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings.
2016-06-15 10:27:13,547 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.WebflowCipherExecutor] - Secret key for signing is not defined. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the signing key
2016-06-15 10:27:13,548 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.WebflowCipherExecutor] - Generated signing key yFviymygFbp6aBsbefENJIqzF2TC3TjYr8BM90OgMyDTahX8IvgGmx9NkmAxCSiVlwqtu6lX4L75tlz0hiS_Hw of size 512. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings.
2016-06-15 10:27:13,548 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.WebflowCipherExecutor] - No encryption key is defined. CAS will attempt to auto-generate keys
2016-06-15 10:27:13,550 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.WebflowCipherExecutor] - Generated encryption key YUAgETufIeKoNAcj of size 16. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings.
```

**cas.log**

```
2016-06-15 10:20:15,958 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-15-ec9hmNl4z9323tGB4GAk-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:15 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:15,958 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-15-ec9hmNl4z9323tGB4GAk-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:15 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:15,981 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-16-Zv45Yg1clIux7BMelg0S-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:15,982 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-16-Zv45Yg1clIux7BMelg0S-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:15 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:15,982 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-16-Zv45Yg1clIux7BMelg0S-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:15 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,001 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-17-Qmc4qYgFeQaUW2FbS27g-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,003 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-17-Qmc4qYgFeQaUW2FbS27g-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,003 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-17-Qmc4qYgFeQaUW2FbS27g-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,023 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-18-Yp7Yug2f00PIcOpHAFae-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,025 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-18-Yp7Yug2f00PIcOpHAFae-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,025 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-18-Yp7Yug2f00PIcOpHAFae-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,054 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-19-oqwcigMG5IDaYgPWHklZ-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,056 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-19-oqwcigMG5IDaYgPWHklZ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,056 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-19-oqwcigMG5IDaYgPWHklZ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,083 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-20-fyBHcJ3CH0mpNRULaXDa-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,084 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-20-fyBHcJ3CH0mpNRULaXDa-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,084 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-20-fyBHcJ3CH0mpNRULaXDa-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,106 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-21-pLy0fxVWe6SdnpbfKv5d-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,107 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-21-pLy0fxVWe6SdnpbfKv5d-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,107 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-21-pLy0fxVWe6SdnpbfKv5d-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,165 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-22-6gDAWzqPUfdssuw1kohO-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,166 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-22-6gDAWzqPUfdssuw1kohO-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,166 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-22-6gDAWzqPUfdssuw1kohO-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,191 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-23-vYzZHCK2LK01I4Aj7CjJ-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,192 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-23-vYzZHCK2LK01I4Aj7CjJ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,192 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-23-vYzZHCK2LK01I4Aj7CjJ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,212 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-24-VkP3mqXIrNUm5cxq3NY3-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,213 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-24-VkP3mqXIrNUm5cxq3NY3-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,213 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-24-VkP3mqXIrNUm5cxq3NY3-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,230 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-25-Hea0JvBXXEdHFs1bGM3z-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,231 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-25-Hea0JvBXXEdHFs1bGM3z-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,231 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-25-Hea0JvBXXEdHFs1bGM3z-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,246 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-26-oycaYlMAUcugtqfuzp6d-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,247 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-26-oycaYlMAUcugtqfuzp6d-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,247 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-26-oycaYlMAUcugtqfuzp6d-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,263 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-27-jRqWbcwgIckXy6prKcLb-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,264 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-27-jRqWbcwgIckXy6prKcLb-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,264 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-27-jRqWbcwgIckXy6prKcLb-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,281 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted ticket [ST-28-eFQBuaUsiqeVNMFjOUHJ-cas01.example.org] for service [https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient] and principal [username]
2016-06-15 10:20:16,282 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-28-eFQBuaUsiqeVNMFjOUHJ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================


2016-06-15 10:20:16,282 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: username
WHAT: ST-28-eFQBuaUsiqeVNMFjOUHJ-cas01.example.org for https://localhost:8443/cas-services/login/cas?client_name=CasClient
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Wed Jun 15 10:20:16 YEKT 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================
```

Comment: Did you edit user-details.properties
 -> # Only 'casuser' is authorized to use cas services management app
casuser=notused,ROLE_ADMIN (Unfortunatly, i dont know the management project)

Comment: I found this line in propertyFileConfigurer.xml
`<util:properties id="casManagementProperties" location="file:/etc/cas/cas-management.properties" />`
and change **location** to cas-management.properties path

And get Error on page: 
Access denied.

You are not authorized to access this resource. Contact your CAS administrator for more info.

Comment: and did you edit the user-details.properties?

Comment: No, why should I edit them if I`m using LDAP?

Comment: Is your CAS server using LDAP for authN? or is the management app using ldap for user access?

Comment: And study this https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Installing-ServicesMgmt-Webapp.html